# Know how much data is missing for both upload and download when syncing (recovering connection) in flutter realm-mongodb

Tags: mongodb, flutter, synchronization, realm

I'm working on a project with flutter and realm-mongodb, I need to know when I recover the connection on the device, the amount of kb left to sync both upload and download. How can I know that information?

I have not found information to do it

Comment: Welcome to SO. In Swift, there's a [SyncSession](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm-sdks/swift/latest/Extensions/SyncSession.html#/s:So14RLMSyncSessionC10RealmSwiftE17ProgressDirectionO) that contains data about the sync - including a Progress structure that contains more granular information about the sync. It has, for example *transferrableBytes* that contains the total number of transferrable bytes (bytes that have been transferred, plus bytes pending transfer). I am sure that's available in other SDK's too.

Comment: I'm using the package "realm: 1.0.3" on flutter(dart) which contains ProgressDirection but I can't find any example of how to implement it

Comment: Ugh. Well that's frustrating - it doesn't seem to be supported at this time. Additionally, the docs specifically state *Do not rely on ProgressDirection.download for download progress notifications* so I would avoid that. If there's isn't one open already - I suggest a feature request to move this along as that functionality would be a nice feature to heave with large datasets.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Finally, a native android application will be made that will read the information from realm. Every time the connection is lost and it is recovered in the other application (made with flutter), we will receive in this new app the amount of data that is missing to synchronize with realm. How can I query this data mentioned above from my new native android app?

Comment: I think you're spending a lot of time on an issue that may not exist. Realm writes are transactional - either it all passes or all fails. You will never have a situation where only some of the data in a write is written. The SDK's do not provide a granular level of sync detail to be able to determine what sync'd and what didn't. In other words, you can't see that the last 10 bytes of data didn't sync, so get those bytes and sync them the next time the connection is live. I may not understand the use case but this is all handled by Realm on the back-end with no input from the developer.

Comment: Is there a way to tell if everything has synced or if it has failed?

Comment: Yes there is! The documentation for all SDK's include details and code examples of handing errors - this includes errors in sync'ing as well as others. See [Handling Errors](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/flutter/sync/handle-sync-errors/)